# Semmelweis had no explanation?

Tags: biology, medicine

That Semmelweis noticed a huge drop in mortality among new mothers simply by having doctors wash their hands between patients.

But according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ignaz_Semmelweis he did not have an explanation for why this effect was occurring. This is puzzling: microorganisms were not news and surely some people suggested that they might cause disease? I know even in ancient times invisible agents or seeds might cause illness.

Comment: From the linked article in Wikipedia: " His findings earned widespread acceptance only years after his death, when Louis Pasteur confirmed the germ theory, giving Semmelweis' observations a theoretical explanation ..." In other words, Semmelweis was not able to point to a proven mechanism of action that explained his observations. Compare, for example, with Wegener's hypothesis of continental drift which was called into question as it was missing a mechanism of action until seafloor spreading etc was discovered decades later.